# Continue for loop after the animation has finished

Tags: jquery, loops, animation

I am trying to visualize the shellsort algorithm.

```
  function shellSort (a) {

  for (var h = a.length; h = parseInt(h / 2);) {
      for (var i = h; i < a.length; i++) {
          var k = getInt(a[i].id);
          var helper = a[i];
          for (var j = i; j >= h && k < getInt(a[j - h].id); j -= h){

            var idA = a[j].id;
            var idB = a[j - h].id;

            setTimeout(function(){
              animatTthis($('#' + idA), 500);
              animatTthis($('#' + idB), 500);
              console.log('animate!');
            },250);

            a[j] = a[j - h];
          }
          a[j] = helper;
      }
  }
  return a;  
}
```

First I create random Numbers and add them as a p-tag inside a div. After that i push all the divs with the fitting class in an Array which is given to the shellsort function above.
This works fine but I can't get the animation to work properly.

```
  function animatTthis(targetElement, speed) {
  $(targetElement).animate({ top: "50px"},
  {
      duration: speed,
      complete: function ()
      {
          setTimeout(function(){
            $(targetElement).animate({ top: "0px" },{
              duration: speed,
              complete: function (){
                  console.log('animate!');
              }
            });
        },500);
      }
  });
};
```

It only animates the last two Divs in the loop.

My intention was that the two Divs which are swapped slide down and back again. The shellsort is supposed to continue after that.

I have tried many diffrent solutions but I can't get it to work the way I want it to.

The finished version should visually swap the two divs.. so if you might have a quick solution or a link for me that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

edit:

The HTML and CSS used:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Shell Sort</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 >Shell- sort</h1>
<button id='randomNumbers'>Numbers!</button> // creeates random numbers
<button id='okay'>Okay!</button>  //starts the shellsort
<div id='container'>
  <div id="element1" class="test"><p class='value' id='e1ID'></p></div>
  <div id="element2" class="test"><p class='value' id='e2ID'></p></div>
  <div id="element3" class="test"><p class='value' id='e3ID'></p></div>
  <div id="element4" class="test"><p class='value' id='e4ID'></p></div>
  <div id="element5" class="test"><p class='value' id='e5ID'></p></div>
  <div id="element6" class="test"><p class='value' id='e6ID'></p></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
h1{
    color:red;
}
.value{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.test{
        background-color: red;
        height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
}
```

There is nothing functional here but maybe it helps.. :)

The jquery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

//#############---giveRandomNumbers----#############
  $("#randomNumbers").click(function(){
    var numbers = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      var $random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      numbers.push($random);
    }

      for(var int = 0; int < numbers.length; int++){
          $('#e'+(int + 1)+'ID').text(numbers[int]);
      }
    });

  $('#okay').click(function(){
      var $ids = $('.test');
      shellSort($ids);

      for(var int = 0; int < $ids.length; int++){
        console.log(getInt($ids[int].id));
        $("#container").append($ids[int]);
      }
    });

    //#############---getIntegerOfDiv----#############
  function getInt(id) {
    var $number = parseInt($('#'+ id).find("p").text());
    return $number;
  };
  //#############---animationCarry----#############
  function createAnimation(a, b) {
      return function() {
          animatTthis($('#' + a), 500);
          animatTthis($('#' + b), 500);
      };
  }
//#############---animation----#############
  function animatTthis(targetElement, speed) {
  $(targetElement).animate({ top: "50px"},
  {
      duration: speed,
      complete: function (){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $(targetElement).animate({ top: "0px" },{
              duration: speed,
              complete: function (){
                  console.log('animate!');
              }
            });
        },500);
      }
  });
};
//#############---shellSort----#############
  function shellSort (a) {

      for (var h = a.length; h = parseInt(h / 2);) {
          for (var i = h; i < a.length; i++) {
              var k = getInt(a[i].id);
              var helper = a[i];
              for (var j = i; j >= h && k < getInt(a[j - h].id); j -= h){
                a[j] = a[j - h];
                var idA = a[j].id;
                var idB = a[j - h].id;
                setTimeout(createAnimation(idA, idB), 250);

              }
              a[j] = helper;
          }
      }
      return a;
  }
});
```

Comment: could you please add related HTML and CSS here?

Comment: thanks for sharing HTML and CSS. I was checking your code but couldn't able to locate the code which gets called on create random button and also function `getInt`. So could be please share code present in your `script.js` file. It will be easy to fix the code once we can reproduce it here. Thanks.

Comment: I added the jquery code to my post! Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: I will check it soon. Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the variables used in the timeout are just referenced - so for each loop a new timeout is set for the current val (= expected) + the values in the function of the previously created timeout function are modified as well (= unexpected, i guess).

A possible solution would be to do the animation not asynchronously.
Maybe it would also work to create a function via a "currying"-function ala

```
function createAnimation(a, b) {
    return function() {
        animatTthis($('#' + a), 500);
        animatTthis($('#' + b), 500);
    };
}
```

and in our sort:

```
setTimeout(createAnimation(idA, idB), 250);
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Animation at the same time is another problem then you asked for.
Anyways: The problem is, that the iteration is much faster then 250ms, so all the animations starting at the almost same time.

You need to queue the animation via the animation callbacks one after another. My suggestion is to first do your sorting and gather information how to animate. Afterwards you can create a chained function to animate as required.

I've created an example which replaces some of your original methods by an "Animator" which is able to gather the required information and performing the animation afterwards:

```
var Animator = {

 toAnimate: [],

 add: function(a, b) {
    Animator.toAnimate.push({
        a: '#' + a,
        b: '#' + b
    });
 },

 execute: function() {

     var lastCallback = function() {
         Animator.toAnimate = [];
     };

     for (var idx = 0; idx<Animator.toAnimate.length; idx++) {
         var elem = Animator.toAnimate[idx];
         var animateB = Animator.createAnimation(elem.b, 500, lastCallback);
         var animateA = Animator.createAnimation(elem.a, 500, animateB);

         lastCallback = animateA;
     }

     lastCallback();
 },

 createAnimation: function(id, speed, cb) {
     console.log('creating animation for ' + id);
     return function() {
        $(id).animate({top: '50px'}, speed, function() {
           $(id).animate({top: '0px'}, speed, function() {
              if (typeof(cb) === 'function') {
                 cb();
              }
           });
        });
     }
 }
}
```

This seems to work from an animation point of view, checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91Lp7k90/

Apart from this, the elemt id's seem not to be correctly, that's why i've added some console output's as well...

Comment: Sadly, that does not seem to fix the problem :/

Comment: Thank you for your great effort!!!
I'm going to take a closer look at it later today and report back :)

Comment: Sorry for the long wait.
This is not exactly what I had in mind. I want the two objects that are being compared to move together at the same time. Here every div is going back and forth the number of times it was swapped to get to its final position.
Nontheless- again, a big thank you for the work you have put ionto this!